# Jquery freezing on show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, freeze

Can someone tell me if I'm insane or where I'm going wrong.  I've tried this on multiple browsers and it freezes jQuery when you do show().

I can't figure it out,  I've tried multiple ways of twisting the code around, and no matter what, when .show() is called, it freezes and won't work until the page is reloaded.

The intent is to show a few different options and if a user clicks and it's a paid option it shows the additional information required.  THE CRAZY THING is when you delete most of the li's it works fine. BUT when you add the li's back in the page it doesn't work.  It works for 2 or 3 clicks then freezes. Firebug shows no errors, just doesnt do anything. Interestingly, jquery on the rest of the page still works, when the option part is frozen.  I would appreciate any constructive ideas. Thanks!

DOESN'T work joopk.com/signup
WORKS//////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#signupoptions .signupoption").click(clickedoption);
});
function clickedoption() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("payoption")) {
    $("#signupadditionalinfo").show();
  }else {
    $("#signupadditionalinfo").hide();
  }
   $("#signupoptions .signupoption").removeClass("optionselected");
   $(this).addClass("optionselected");
}
```

I've taken out the details for brevity, but the general html is as follows:

```
 <div id="signupoptions">
                            <div id="signupoptiondescription">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Joopk.com CMS</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="signupoptionsocial" class="signupoption optionselected">
                                <h3>
                                    Social</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="check"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="signupoptionbusiness" class="signupoption payoption">
                                <h3>
                                    Business</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="check"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="signupoptiondeveloper" class="signupoption payoption">
                                <h3>
                                    Developer</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="check"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="signupadditionalinfo" class="container" style="display: none;">
                            <h3>
                                Additional Information</h3>

                        </div>
```

Comment: I forgot to paste in the rest of the clicked option, it is as follows:             $("#signupoptions .signupoption").removeClass("optionselected");
            $(this).addClass("optionselected");

Comment: The removeclass removes the class from all of the divs, then the add class adds it to the clicked one.  That works fine.

Comment: The whole thing works here: http://joopk.com/testpage.htm, it's the exact same code.

Comment: OK.  I made it work, I have ABSOLUTELY no idea why it works, but for some reason it works.  I had the class on signupadditionalinfo as container, it was in a div with a class of container.  I removed the class on the additional info cause it was unnecessary, and viola, now it's working.  I really would like to know why.

Answer (score 1):

The clicking logic was off...  Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/3JMA9/1/

Basically, take a look at the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#signupoptions .signupoption").click(function(){
        clickedoption($(this).attr('class'));
    });
});

function clickedoption(myclass) {
    if (myclass.indexOf("payoption") !== -1) {
        $("#signupadditionalinfo").show();
    } else {
        $("#signupadditionalinfo").hide();
    }
    $("#signupoptions .signupoption").removeClass("optionselected");
    $(this).addClass("optionselected");
}
```

The CSS is there to help you see what is going on.

Comment: I appreciate the help!  That definitely works.  I'd +1 you, but can't until I get a 15 rep.  But really, thanks!  I've spent the past 4 hours trying to find the reason. For learning purposes.

Comment: The only question I have is isn't the hasClass("payoption") essentially the same as passing in the class and seeing if the index is -1?

Comment: It is the same, functionally.  However, the key to this was that you separated the action into a separate function.  `$(this).attr('class')` was what needed to be passed to the function, and the result of that is a string.  So you needed to use `indexOf` to parse the string.  If you included everything in the `click` anonymous function, you could have also used the `hasClass` option.

Comment: I know you can't +1, but if this is the right answer, you should accept it as the answer (with a check mark).  Thank you!